# How do I handle DB model migrations in pip installable package

Tags: django, django-models, pip, django-south, setup.py

I am developing a Django app that can be installed via pip for use within a larger project.
I have DB models in this app.  I plan to use South in case I need to do any migrations in future versions.

Should I make South an install requirement and then have the user manually run migration(s) or should I do it automatically in the setup.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running migrations is a part of an application setup/startup routine, in my opinion it is out of the scope of installation.

Comment: I tend to agree with this answer, I am just trying to figure out the common practice.  So an acceptable set of instructions to use the app would be:

1. pip install myPackage
2. Add south and myPackage to the INSTALLED_APPLICATIONS
3. run syncdb
4. run migrate myPackage

Answer (score 0):

If I was the user, I prefer one setup script can figure everything out. And it is not a complex function, why not do it automatically.